# We have coded an Admin Panel with using Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, build

[image]

We have coded an Admin Panel with using Angular 2 project. That is working well in localhost but not working in web environment or in server. Do we must do some specific configurations or sth like that ?

Comment: More info pls..

Answer (score 0):

This Angular2 project is working well on localhost but what is needed for deployment on web server ? After develepment is made in my localhost, what is the next step for sending this project on webserver to be displayed? Should only a single "dist" folder be sent to webserver or is there any additional configuration needed on server ?